# It is not possible to use Robinson projection in matplotlib-basemap over a specific region?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to plot a map in Matplotlib-Basemap using the Robinson projection (or similar). Most of the Matplotlib examples on this issue are awkward and at some point useless for beginners like me. What I want to do? I simply want something like this: [image]

May somebody else give me some insights?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read tutorial here: http://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/first_map.html

Comment: Thanks, but I already have plotted various maps with Basemap. My goal is to plot a map exactly or similar as the one I posted here (i.e., with the borders showing the Earth's curvature. I have used other projections, which work for a specific region, but Robinson, Hammer, and others are for global maps. Thus, I was wondering if somebody else know a similar projection but NOT limited to global maps in Basemap.